# Any one explain the below code and what is its output?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

The c++ code
I am unable to understand the pointer inside the class.
What does this line `char *txtTemp = NULL` represents?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
class BixString
{
    char txtName[20]; 
    public:
    BixString(char *txtTemp = NULL)
    {
        if(txtTemp != NULL)
        strcpy(txtName, txtTemp);
    }
    void Display(void)
    {
        cout<<txtName;
    }
};
int main()
{
    char *txtName = (char*)malloc(10);
    strcpy(txtName, "IndiaBIX");
    *txtName = 48;
    BixString objTemp(txtName);
    cout<< sizeof(txtName);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I suggest you get [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read a little.

Answer (score 0):

It's a default argument, so you can call `BixString()` with no arguments, and the txtTemp variable will be `NULL`.